# Как вывести все записи из одной таблицы, встречающиеся определенное количество раз в другой таблице MsSQL

Tags: sql-server

Есть 2 таблицы - t1, содержащая перечень названий и их id и t2, содержащая название событий, связанных с id из первой. Во второй таблице нет названий, только id. Подскажите, как вывести перечень названий из первой таблицы, которые встречаются во второй более определенного кол-ва раз. Если не использовать Having

Comment: Количества посчитать в подзапросе, а отбор и присоединение наименований сделать во внешнем запросе. Тогда будет не HAVING, а WHERE.

Answer (score 1):

Можно, конечно и в WHERE подзапрос запилить, но вероятно так будет медленнее работать.

Вот запрос для вывода событий, произошедших более 5 раз:

```
SELECT  t1.Id,
        Name
FROM t1
JOIN
(
    SELECT t2.Id
    FROM t2
    GROUP BY t2.Id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
) AS t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение, о котором говорит @Akina

Скорее всего у автора вопроса нет необходимости оптимизировать запрос, а именно стоит конкретная задачка, без HAVING

```
DECLARE @NeedCount INT = 5    

SELECT  
    t1.Id,
    t1.Name
FROM t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t2.Id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM t2
    GROUP BY t2.Id
) AS t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
WHERE t2.cnt > @NeedCount
```

Comment: Тут видимо просто студенческая задача, потому такие условия. Иного не могу предположить)

Comment: Спасибо, люди добрые!! Да, дело именно в том, что задача была сделать без Хевинг)

Comment: @Den.di а почему нельзя использовать HAVING?

Comment: @Vitaliy Zlobin, вот Вы писали про оптимизатор, и то, что он может исходный запрос переписать по своему усмотрению. А есть возможность увидеть результат работы оптимизатора каким то образом? Или это незримая штука, которую можно понять только по плану выполнения?

Comment: @AndrewNikolaev нужно анализировать план, но не картинки, а свойство предиката для подзапроса. Либо сравнить оба плана выполнения - если одинаковые, значит оптимизатор догадался как лучше, но на него лучше не полагаться, т.е. завтра будет кривая статистика и план будет тоже другой и тоже кривой.